# dict of dict to csv for user inputs

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, nested, iteration

I have created an employee database for n user inputs with various details like idno,name,position and salary. employee database works perfectly in python but when I try to write it as csv

Here are my codes:

```
import csv
d={}
d1={}

n=int(raw_input("Enter the number of employees :"))
for i in range(n):
    emp_name=raw_input("Enter the name of employee :")
    emp_idno=raw_input("Enter the idno of employee :")
    emp_position=raw_input("Enter the position of employee :")
    emp_salary=int(raw_input("Enter the salary of employee :"))

    d1={emp_idno: {"Name": emp_name, "Position":emp_position, "Salary":emp_salary}}
    d.update(d1)
    print d

for key,value in d.iteritems():
    print key,value

    with open('12file1.csv','w') as f:
        w = csv.writer(f)
        w.writerow(['Idno','Name','Position', 'Salary'])
        w.writerows(d.iteritems())

with open('12file1.csv','w') as f:
    w = csv.writer(f)
    w.writerow(['Idno','Name','Position', 'Salary'])
    for keys, values in d.iteritems():
        w.writerows({'Idno':key,'Name':value['Name'],'Position':value["Position"], 'Salary':value["Salary"]})
```

My dict of dict should look like

```
{idno: {name,position,salary}}
```

I'm trying to iterate dict of dict and then write it to csv. It would be great if I could get any easier way to write nested dict as csv.

My csv output should be

```
Idno    Name    Position    Salary
101     Abc      Trainee     12000
102     Def      Fresher      8000
```

Comment: Is the code you have (the second for loop) producing incorrect results? Looks fine to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two points

- In the line in which you write your values,

  ```
   w.writerows({'Idno':key,'Name':value['Name'],'Position':value["Position"], 'Salary':value["Salary"]})
  ```

The variable used in loop is `values` and the one that you access inside is `value` as

```
{'Idno':keys,'Name':values['Name'],'Position':values["Position"], 'Salary':values["Salary"]}
```

- to write the dict to csv,

Make use of python [csv.DictWriter()](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter.writeheader) to write you header.

```
with open('12file1.csv','w') as f:
    w = csv.DictWriter(f,fieldnames=['Idno','Name','Position', 'Salary'])
    w.writeheader()
    for keys,values in d.iteritems():
        w.writerow({'Idno':keys,'Name':values['Name'],'Position':values["Position"], 'Salary':values["Salary"]})
```

That is,

```
import csv
d={}
d1={}

n=int(raw_input("Enter the number of employees :"))
for i in range(n):
    emp_name=raw_input("Enter the name of employee :")
    emp_idno=raw_input("Enter the idno of employee :")
    emp_position=raw_input("Enter the position of employee :")
    emp_salary=int(raw_input("Enter the salary of employee :"))

    d1={emp_idno: {"Name": emp_name, "Position":emp_position, "Salary":emp_salary}}
    d.update(d1)
    print d

for key,value in d.iteritems():
    print key,value

with open('12file1.csv','w') as f:
    w = csv.DictWriter(f,fieldnames=['Idno','Name','Position', 'Salary'])
    w.writeheader()
    for keys,values in d.iteritems():
        w.writerow({'Idno':keys,'Name':values['Name'],'Position':values["Position"], 'Salary':values["Salary"]})
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

As you are working with dictionaries, it would make more sense to make use of [`csv.DictWriter()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html?highlight=dictwriter#csv.DictWriter) to work with your output CSV file. When using the CSV library, you should always open using files in binary mode, so to write you need `wb` format, otherwise you can end up with extra blank lines in your file.

The following should give you what you want:

```
import csv

d = {}
d1 = {}

n = int(raw_input("Enter the number of employees: "))

for i in range(n):
    emp_name = raw_input("Enter the name of employee: ")
    emp_idno = raw_input("Enter the idno of employee: ")
    emp_position = raw_input("Enter the position of employee: ")
    emp_salary = int(raw_input("Enter the salary of employee: "))

    d1 = {emp_idno: {"Name": emp_name, "Position":emp_position, "Salary":emp_salary, "Idno":emp_idno}}
    d.update(d1)
    print

with open('12file1.csv','wb') as f:
    w = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=['Idno', 'Name', 'Position', 'Salary'])
    w.writeheader()

    for idno, employee in d.iteritems():
        w.writerow(employee)
```

Note, as you are saving your entries as dictionaries, the order will not be preserved. It might make more sense to use a list of dictionaries rather than a dictionary of dictionaries. Note, I have added the ID number as a key in the dictionary, otherwise it would need to be added when doing the `writerow()`